# Google cloud compute instance metrics taking up disk space

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a google cloud compute instance set up but it's getting low on disk space. It looks like it is the `/mnt/stateful_partition/var/lib/metrics` directory taking up a significant amount of space (3+gb). I assume this is the compute metrics but I can't find any way to safely remove these other than just deleting the files. Is this going to cause any issues?

Answer (score 1):

The path you are referring are File System directories that are used for the GCE VM instance, and you are correct that the metrics folder is safe to be removed. To learn more about these directories, see [Disks and file system](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/disks-and-filesystem) overview.

I would also suggest to [create a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#create_regional_snapshot) first if you wanted to make sure that the changes you will do on your instance won't affect your system performance. So that you can easily  revert it back to your previous instance state.